# jQuery version of Linq's Where()

Tags: jquery

I want to use jQuery to get the checked radio button out of a radio button set.

The form object here is not a jQuery object but rather "normal" javascript object.

I want the following:

```
//"where" should fliter the jQuery Array
var myVal = $(form.RadioSet).where(':checked').val();
```

I know I can get my results with this:

```
var myVal = $(form).find('input[name=RadioSet]:checked').val();
```

But that's a little bit more typing with the "input" and the "name" syntax.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Are those the only checkboxes in the form?

Comment: You mean Radio buttons? Nope. But they are the only ones with the name "RadioSet". Every set on the page has their unique name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think .filter() is what you're looking for...

as in:

```
var myVal = $(form.RadioSet).filter(':checked').val();
```

Comment: Yup, still waiting for the "You can accept an answer in 1 minute" box to go. :)

Answer (score 3):

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

```
var myVal = $(form.RadioSet).filter(':checked').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using [jQuery.grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) ? It may be quite useful.